# Clojure: add element to a vector inside a map

Tags: dictionary, vector, clojure

I have this map

```clj
(def m {:a "aaa" :b {:c ["ss" "gg"]}})
```

I want to update it to this (add "uu" to the vector :c):

```clj
{:a "aaa" :b {:c ["ss" "gg" "uu"]}}
```

This is what I came up with and I hate it:

```clj
(assoc-in m [:b :c] (conj (get-in m [:b :c]) "uu"))
```

How *should* I be doing it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(update-in m [:b :c] conj "uu")
```

The way I think of it is that `update-in` *gets you there* and calls a function that receives not only the state that is *there*, but also the remaining parameters. So here `conj` will be called with `["ss" "gg"]` and `"uu"`, and the value of key `:c` in the data structure will become `["ss" "gg" "uu"]`.

`assoc-in` does not get any initial state, hence in your example you are having to labour to create what is *there* all over again.

Comment: but beware the pitfall: if the key is absent in a map, the `conj` would create a list, not a vector: `(update-in m [:b :d] conj "xxx")` => `{:a "aaa", :b {:c ["ss" "gg"], :d ("xxx")}}`. to avoid this you should handle the `nil` values, like this: `(update-in m [:b :d] (fnil conj []) "xxx")` => `{:a "aaa", :b {:c ["ss" "gg"], :d ["xxx"]}}`